# Can i show or hide content based on Sender Profile or Send Classification in business unit?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

To marketing cloud developers
Is there a way to show/hide content based on the orgs "Sender Profile" or "Send Classification" with AMPscript?

The scenario is that I only want to show the profile center link when it is a commercial email.
Today it is solved with 2 templates with each different content block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no personalisation string as such, to help you identify either of these. You can use this “hack” to lookup the job details of your send, and switch your footer accordingly:

```
IF _messagecontext == 'SEND' THEN
  SET @status = Lookup("_Job","SendClassificationType","JobID", jobid)
  
 IF @status == 'Default Commercial' THEN
  SET @type = 'Commercial'
 ELSE
  SET @type = 'Transactional'
 ENDIF  
 ENDIF
```